# Punctured disk and a manifold homeomorphic to a punctured disk are biholomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $M$ be a complex manifold which is homeomorphic to the disk $D:=|z|<1$, suppose that $m\in M$, define $M^*:=M\setminus \{m\}$. Then we can we show that $M^*$ and $D^*:=0<|z|<1$ are biholomorphic?

As someone pointed out, when $M=\mathbb{C}$ it is not true, but I wonder under what condition it is true and how to show that?

Comment: Is $\Bbb{C}$ homeomorphic to $D$, is $\Bbb{C}^*$ biholomorphic to $D^*$ ? With more conditions it reduces to the existence of a non-vanishing holomorphic one-form and to the Riemann mapping theorem.

Comment: @reuns for the more conditions, what do you assume?

Comment: You should assume that $M$ is conformal to the unit disk. Then the claim is clearly true. Otherwise, it is clearly false.